# Create a per-master-object id for each object belogning to a master object

Tags: django, primary-key

If we supose that we have the following model:

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=30)

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=30)
    mainmodel = models.ForeignKey(MainModel)

    class Meta:
        unique_together(("mainmodel","id"))
```

I would like to have id-s for the SecondModel like this:

```
mainmodel: 1
id: 1

mainmodel: 1
id: 2

mainmodel: 2
id: 1

mainmodel: 2
id: 2
```

And what I get is the following:

```
mainmodel: 1
id: 1

mainmodel: 1
id: 2

mainmodel: 2
id: 3

mainmodel: 2
id: 4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unique_together` is a constraint, not an id-generator.

To achieve what you want, just an integer field to your `SecondModel`, add this field to your `unique_together` and override the `save` method of the model to set the correct value of this field. For instance, you can do something like this:

```
class SecondModel(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=30)
    mainmodel = models.ForeignKey(MainModel)
    mainid = models.Integerfield()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.mainid:
            self.mainid = SecondModel.objects.get(mainmodel=self.mainmodel).count()+1
        super(SecondModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together(("mainmodel","mainid"),)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is very close for what I'm looking for. The only problem I see, is what happens when the id is taken.

Comment: Which id you mean ? As I have answered, the normal ``id`` of the model will be a primary key getting auto-increased values. So let's forget about that. Now, what we do care about is the ``mainid`` (the ``id`` in your schema is named ``mainid`` in my answer). Each time you save a ``SecondModel`` object containing a ``ForeignKey`` to a specific ``MainModel`` the ``count()`` will be increased -- so the ``mainid`` won't ever be taken for that specific ``mainmodel`` (problems will start appearing if you allow deletions of ``SecondModel`` objects but I leave that as an excersise to the reader).

Comment: Ok, you have understood what I was wondering. But you are right, you can leave as an excercise to the reader ;) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your question text completely contradicts your title. Using `unique_together` in that way implies that you only want *one* SecondModel for each individual MainModel: in which case a OneToOne field is more appropriate than a ForeignKey with unique_together.

Secondly, what you are asking is impossible. Primary keys are unique: you can't have multiple instances of SecondModel all with the same id value, even if they have separate parents.

Perhaps you should explain what problem you are actually trying to solve here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to call this title. And no, I don't think using unique_together implies I only want one SecondModel for each individual MainModel.

The problem I pretend to solve is avoiding to have very large id numbers for a single SecondModel instance.

Answer (score 0):

The ids are asigned by model ... so if you need any other specification, you will have to make  them.